# How do I get the six hidden achievements in Indie Game: The Movie?

Tags: achievements, indie-game-the-movie

I see that there are [six (6) hidden Steam achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/207080/achievements) (Feature Complete, Extra Lives, Nice to Meat You, Teh Internets, Bonus Levels, and Behind the Scenes) with no descriptions and I have no idea how to get them. Do I need to rewatch the movie if I have already? Can I skip around? What are the unlock conditions? Where are they hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this site](http://astats.astats.nl/astats/Steam_Game_Info.php?AppID=207080), the achievements are as follows:

> Feature Complete - Watch Indie Game: The Movie.
>
> Extra Lives - Watch all the Indie Game: The Movie extras.
>
> Nice to Meat You - Listen to Team Meat's Indie Game: The Movie
>   commentary track.
>
> Teh Internets - Press the Twitter or Facebook buttons on the Indie
>   Game: The Movie extras menu.
>
> Bonus Levels - Watch all the Indie Game: The Movie Special Edition
>   segments.
>
> Behind the Scenes - Listen to the Indie Game: The Movie director's
>   commentary track.
>
> Game Master - Get a perfect score in Indie Game: The Movie: The Game.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how they work? Can you skip sections, or does everything have to run straight through?

Comment: I had to watch the segments straight through. Might have been because I switched computers halfway through.